# Dirty Rects grouping

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a pretty simple scrollable calendar UI:

[image]

But from time to time calendar blinks during scrolling. I have looked at WPF Performance Suite and noticed there is a significant amount of Dirty Rects (about 400):

[image]

The markup of the calendar is ItemsControl which binds Days (only visible days are bound). Looks like WPF redraws day by day (so that's why there are so many dirty rects for such a simple UI). I thought may be there is a way to tell WPF not to redraw many small rectangles but redraw the whole ItemsControl at once (similar to what Double Buffering did in the all good days of WinForms).

P. S. WritableBitmap fixes the problem but I hope there is a nicer way

**Update.** Here is how Calendar looks if I switch the "Show dirty-region update overlay" option on:

[image]

So WPF correctly finds the dirty region. The question is why it decides to use so many dirty-rects to redraw it. My guess is that it happens because of the space between days (one or two pixels of white) which is the same during scrolling.

**Update 2.**

Here is the markup of the Calender:

```
<ItemsControl  Panel.ZIndex="1" Grid.Column="1" 
       ItemsSource="{Binding Days}" 
       VerticalAlignment="Center" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Margin="1,0,1,0" Padding="0,0,3,0" 
                  CornerRadius="1" Width="28" Height="28" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Border.Background>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DayOfWeekToColorConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="IsWeekend"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Border.Background>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource TextStyle}" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Label  Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" 
                          Content="{Binding Date.Day}" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Have you tried using ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll = true so you scroll only whole days? Probably makes no sense to scroll half a day anyway.

Comment: @SoMoS, ScrollViewer is not used here at all

Comment: try using "Show dirty-region update overlay" and "Draw software rendering with purple tint" it will show you the redrawn part of your app. posting your code would probably help diagnosing the problem

Comment: How are you scrolling then?

Comment: @makc, it shows that the whole Calendar is dirty-rect (it doesn't show there are multiple of them). Also from time to time during scrolling it draws some part of Calendar as purple (so software rendering is used but not always)

Comment: @SoMoS, scrolling is made via ViewModel

Comment: @Idsa I guess you'll have to post the relevant code otherwise i dont believe anyone would be able to guess the problem

Comment: Why don´t you use a `VirtualizingStackPanel` as ItemsPanel for your ItemsControl?

Comment: @Jehof, as I bind only the days which should be currently displayed (in other words, scrolling is implemented in ViewModel) it doesn't seem like I need UiVirtualization

Comment: You should expect this behavior then depending on the amount of dates are bound IMO.  Every time you scroll, everything with be marked as dirty because the UI needs to be sync'd for when the item actually comes into view.  If you use something that can virtualize, then the only thing to get drawn are those items that are currently in the view. So you might have 22 dirty rects instead of your 400.

Comment: @Idsa have you tried it? You only need to change your ItemsPanel to `<ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>` and see if it performs better.

Comment: The component is simple, so you can try to combine different parts of code: try remove border with multibinding; try to render with static values of days; change container type as @Jehof advised. Unfortunately, there is no jsfiddle for wpf, it would be much easier to help you.

Comment: If you haven't solved this, would you mind adding the style.xaml resourcedictionary for the "TextStyle" and "LabelStyle", plus your DayOfWeekToColorConverter implementation and a simple object that we can use for databinding for testing purposes.

Comment: Do you have any animations going? When changing from a day to another? In that case, using "snap to device pixel" could help.

Answer (score 1):

I would have added to the comment list but I don't have enough reputation to do so. Another possible reason why you may be seeing the blinking is due to a slow down in UI performance caused by a GC. Depending on how your code is working (only part of it is posted) you may be creating and orphaning a lot of objects that will eventually cause a GC to fire and could potentially cause a slight slowdown in the UI. You should be able to see if this is the case by running [perfmon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4bz2147%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and seeing if a GC is fired every time the UI blinks.

I figured I should mention this possibility as well since it doesn't seem to have been considered and is something that can be tested with running a trace of GC calls while your application is running.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an answer, but it is a suggestion. I thought may be as the xaml inside  will be repeated as many times as there are items in your **Days** collection, it improves the rendering if we have the coding as minimal as possible.

1. Move styles for **Border** to static resource **BorderStyle**
2. Change **Label** to **TextBlock** (Label has some funny preprocessing done. ex: Remove **_** underscores)
3. As only one property is bound, we can take out **MultiBinding** and put simple binding
4. You've used a converter for border **Background**. You can create a property in **Date** which returns color based on WeekDay.

   ```
           <DataTemplate>
               <Border Style="{StaticResource BorderStyle}" Background="{Binding Date.DayBackgroundColor}">
                   <StackPanel>
                       <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource TextStyle}"/>
                       <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" Text="{Binding Date.Day}" />
                   </StackPanel>
               </Border>
           </DataTemplate>
   ```

Like when you change an SQL query slightly the query plan changes and optimization occurs, these changes may improve WPF's rendering plan :)

Answer (score 1):

Here the cause of redrawing could be due to unwanted property changed notification fired from the code for the **Days** collection. This could cause rebinding of the whole list resulting in blinking.

Try using [visual studio profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx) to narrow down the cause and hence resolve it.
 Profiler is available in premium and ultimate versions of VS studio.